# How to run an executable file in GitLab CI/CD script using powershell

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm stuck in what seems to be a basic thing. I'm trying to run `conan.exe` which is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe`. The errors I get are either

```
.\C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe : The term '.\C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\"C:\Program Files` (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\C:\Program Fi...conan\conan.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

or

```
x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:22
+ .\C:\Program Files` (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe
+                      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried a combination of `"`, `'`, using ` for spaces, using & at the start (doesn't work since it's reserved for GitLab Runner). I'm out of ideas and my google searches don't seem to help specifically for gitlab ci/cd context.

This is the latest .gitlab-ci.yml I tried:

```
stages:
    - build
    - publish

test_build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - \& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe"
    tags:
        - build
```

With this error:

```
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script663599467\script.ps1:229 char:2
+ \& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan\conan.exe"
+  ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double 
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
 
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Anyone has any idea what could work?

Comment: Maybe try to use `Start-Process` instead of the ampersand.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I just got it to work with `"& \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Conan\\conan\\conan.exe\""`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here Is the answer](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4781). In short:

```
script:
    - 'powershell.exe D:\app\CiTest.exe'
```

While CiTest.exe is a dotnet framework 4.8 console application.